# Why can't I call this static method?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

My utility class and its method (not sure if @AuraEnabled is required here, but I've got it in there just in case):

```
public class GetPhoneNumberPrice {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Decimal byCountry(String IsoCountry) 
    {
        Decimal basePrice;
        //api call and JSON parsing
        return basePrice;
    }    
}
```

And then here's the class where I'm trying to call it:

```
public with sharing class FindAvailablePhoneNumbers {
     @AuraEnabled
     public static List<PhoneNumberWrapper> findNumbers(List<String> params) 
        {
            String IsoCountry = params[2];
            //yada yada yada

            // declare my variable with default value
            Decimal basePrice = 1.0;

            if(IsoCountry != 'US')
            {   
                basePrice = GetPhoneNumberPrice.byCountry(IsoCountry);
            }
            //more code we never get to because of the error...
         }
    }
```

My class is public, method is static, it all pops up automatically in the IDE, so it's being recognized, no typos, returning the correct data type...

The error I'm getting is right on the line/char where the name of the GetPhoneNumberPrice class starts. Error says:
`Variable does not exist: GetPhoneNumberPrice (47:29)`

Can anyone help me spot my error?

Comment: Well, it seems weird. Prima facie, it looks good and I have verified the same code in my org. It compiled successfully. Can you try saving directly in Salesforce browser?

Comment: You've got a typo somewhere else in your code, and the parser got confused and mistakenly blamed this line of code. This typically happens when you have a malformed query somewhere (like forgetting the word `FROM` or something like that). It's rare to get errors like this, but they usually appear because of invalid syntax in a query.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I've discovered additional info, though I don't know why... the utility class won't push to my scratch org.

Comment: @sfdcfox -- I thought the same thing, but it's fine if I just comment out the line of code where I make the call. The issue is with the utility class not pushing to the scratch org. Without it, that error makes sense.

Comment: @PatMcClellan__c Ah, so the utility class is the issue. I guess you'll need to start there. Maybe revise your question?

Comment: Still tracking it down, but it appears my JSON parsing is causing the class not to push. I commented it out, pushed it, now debugging in Dev Console, which has a bit more detail than VSCode.

Comment: Found the issue -- in my JSON parsing, there was an attribute coming in called 'type', and I was assigning variable names that match. `type` is a key word we can't use as a variable name.